# TreeViewer selections and the Clipboard

Tags: java, swt, jface

Is it possible to place more than one object (which represent `TreeViewer` selections) into the clipboard? Here's my Cut code.

```
static public void Cut(EssentialData dataInst)
{
    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)dataInst.getTreeViewer().getSelection();

    if(selection == null)
    {
        System.err.println("selection received was null");
        return;
    }

    Object[] objects = selection.toArray();

    //because setContents requires a Transfer object for every object sent
    List<Transfer> typesList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
        typesList.add(FileEntryTransfer.getInstance());

    final Clipboard cb = new Clipboard(Display.getCurrent());
    cb.setContents(objects, typesList.toArray(new Transfer[]{}));
    cb.dispose();

    for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
        dataInst.getFileManager().removeEntry((FileEntry)objects[i]);

    dataInst.getTreeViewer().refresh(false);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is place multiple selections, which are instances of `FileEntry`, into the clipboard.

`FileEntryTransfer` is my custom `ByteArrayTransfer` class that I also use for DND. It works well, but I noticed that `setContents()` actually sends it only one `FileEntry` object as opposed to an array of objects (which is what I want).

Any ideas?

[edit]Thanks to vanaprogeja, I sovled it with

```
cb.setContents(new Object[]{ objects }, new Transfer[] { FileEntryTransfer.getInstance() });
```

Comment: Could you use a separate Clipboard object? Sorry, I'm not experienced with this, just throwing it out there.

Comment: To call setContents() for each object? Nah, it doesn't work like that; setContents() replaces whatever is in the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
cb.setContents(new Object[]{ objects },
    new Transfer[] { FileEntryTransfer.getInstance() });
```

Comment: Syntax error, but that definitely put me on the right track.

I just solved it with

    cb.setContents(new Object[]{ objects }, new Transfer[] { FileEntryTransfer.getInstance() });