# SWT Java placing/receiving stuff from clipboard

Tags: eclipse, swt, clipboard

I am trying to write some strings to the clipboard in my Eclipse plugin and I have some strange behavior ...

I am using the predefined TextTransfer Transfer-class which should be sufficient for strings?!
My Problem is, that regardless of the number of strings I put in the clipboard only the very last is actually accessible afterwards - I cannot figure out why.

Placing my stuff in the clipboard seems to work, no exceptions. I doing it this way:

```
        Clipboard cb = new Clipboard(Display.getCurrent());
        Object[] data = transferObjects.toArray(); //My strings, looks good in debug
        Transfer[] transfer = transferHandles.toArray(new Transfer[0]); //as many TextTransfer instances as objects in the data-array
        cb.setContents(data, transfer, DND.CLIPBOARD);
        cb.dispose();
```

I receive it this way:

```
TextTransfer textTransfer = TextTransfer.getInstance();
        Object o = cb.getContents(textTransfer); // "o" contains the value of the above array at position n-1, so only the very last is actually returned
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong? Does anyone see my error?

Comment: You seem to have the same problem that is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8498537/150166

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because (from Java-doc):

> More than one type of data can be placed on the system clipboard at the same time. Setting the data clears any previous data from the system clipboard, regardless of type.